# Angular Firestore Batches and Transactions

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I've been struggling with the theory behind this for a couple of weeks and checked all over the internet but cannot find anything that really helps me so I'm reaching out for the first time to the SO community.

I have 3 collections in Firestore (users, events and transactions). When a new event is added I need to :

1. Add a new document to the **events** collection
2. Update the balance in the **users** document.
3. Add a new document into the **transaction** collections which needs to use the new balance from 2. above.

Now, these must either all be successful or if any one of them fails then they all must fail **and** they must be done in order (I can't use the balance from stage 2 in stage 3 before stage 2 has completed!) This pointed my towards transactions but you can't perform and ADDs in a transaction

> A transaction consists of any number of get() operations followed by any number of write operations such as set(), update(), or delete().

So I looked into batches but again no ADDs allowed

> If you do not need to read any documents in your operation set, you can execute multiple write operations as a single batch that contains any combination of set(), update(), or delete() operations.

So I'm a bit confused.

I started looking into async/await but, although this will wait for the previous action to complete before moving onto the next action, it won't allow me to rollback whenever an error occurs (we'll, not easily!).

My app is in Angular 4 but any Javascript help would be gratefully appreciated.....

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1:

One possible solution is Firebase triggers:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

- Events onCreate trigger to update the balance on a user document
- Users onUpdate trigger to add a transaction document

This also provides the added benefit of not needing to rollback errors. Step 2 will not run if step 1 fails, and step 3 will not run if step 2 fails. There is a possibility of step 2 succeeding, and step 3 failing.

Approach 2:

The set() function works similarly to how add works. One difference is you must set the document ID before setting the data on the particular document. This way, you can use a transaction to update and add a document. If you're using AngularFire2, an example would look like this:

```
this.afs.doc('transactions/' + this.afs.createId()).set(transactionData);
```

You most likely want to use a combination of the two approaches provided above depending on the level of write access the users should have client side. My recommended solution would be to use an events onCreate trigger, and have a single transaction inside the trigger that updates a user and sets a transaction document.

Comment: Hi Eric. Thanks for the reply. Your suggested solution looks like a winner. The only issue I can see is that, when I'm updating the balance in the user document it needs to be within a transaction in case the value gets changed while we're trying to change it. How do I get this transaction within the "outer" single transaction?

Comment: If the balance changes while the document is being updated, the transaction will try again. This is something that is taken care of by firestore automatically. You only need a single transaction with set and update.